# Git Credential Manager for Windows Memory Issue

Tags: git, github, windows-task-scheduler, git-credential-manager

I have a powershell script that pulls the latest commit of a repository from github and then builds it using either msbuild (for .net) or webpack (for angular).  The script itself is run using windows task scheduler, which checks a deployment queue periodically, and then runs a build.  Everything was working fine, however it suddenly started hanging.  We also started getting memory issues on our server.  When I started looking at perfmon during this builds,  i saw git credential manager for windows using massive and increasing amount of memory, taking the server to over 98% of usage [image: screenshot of perfmon]
What's strange is that if I run the script directly on the server, it's fine - this only happens when I run it through the Windows Task Scheduler ( powershell -commmand "script.ps1").  Is there any way to find out why this is happening?

I am using:

git version 2.18.0.windows.1

git credential manager for windows 1.17.0

github windows clients 3.3.6.1

and I am running this on windows server 2012 r2

Comment: You could try writing up an issue here as well: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but there are lots of other helpers you could use instead if you need (e.g. `git config credential.helper wincred`)